# O que e o Dynamic Proxy gerado pelo Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

O que e o Dynamic Proxy gerado pelo Entity Framework? E uma classe? Qual a funcao dela?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O dynamic proxy funciona semelhante ao proxy do nhibernate, ele é um proxy da Entidade (classe POCO). Ele é uma classe que sobrescreve as propriedades virtuais da entidade para poder fazer o lazy load. Que se resume em carregar os dados somente na hora em que eles são requisitados.

O lazy load é muito utilizado em listas de objetos (Ex. Lista de dependentes de um empregado) mas pode ser utilizado em propriedades comuns (Ex. Propriedade string que tenha um texto muito longo).

Dê uma olhada nessa [documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) sobre o Lazy Load, que é a carga sob demanda e o Eager Load que é uma técnica que elimina um problema chamado n+1, onde o ORM faz uma chamada ao BD para buscar 1 registro pai e N registros filhos. Com o eager load você busca tudo em uma chamada só.

Respondendo ao seu comentário:

Proxy é um padrão de projeto (http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern) que cria uma classe substituta que simula a classe original. Os ORMs criam uma classe substituta para fazer o Lazy Load da seguinte maneira: Eles criam uma classe proxy com apenas o ID preenchido e passam como se fosse a classe completa e ficam monitorando as propriedades do proxy. Quando tentamos acessar alguma propriedade que não foi carregada (ex. Nome) o ORM vai até o banco de dados e busca o valor correto. Isso é o lazy load. E você está correto o EF também usa o proxy para monitorar as alterações (change tracking)

Comment: O que e um proxy? Basicamente ele gera uma classe a partir da sobrescrita das propriedades declaradas como virtual para uso do lazy load? Apenas isto? Se nao me engano (e posso estar engano, sou bem confuso) li em algum canto que ele tambem tinha parte no change tracking...

Comment: @CaiqueC. tentei responder suas perguntas de forma simples alterando a resposta. Se não ficou muito claro me informe. Sds.